# Display ms document on a web browser using php or html

Tags: php, html

How can I display an ms word document  to  a web browser  just like the way an image is displayed in html . I am using php and  html , I tried it using iframe but my  idea did not work .

```
<iframe name="houses" src="report.doc" width="580"></iframe>
```

Comment: You can use google doc api to open document in google doc

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
<?php
        $word = new COM("word.application") or die ("Could not initialise MS Word object.");
        $word->Documents->Open(realpath("Sample.doc"));

        // Extract content.
        $content = (string) $word->ActiveDocument->Content;

        echo $content;

        $word->ActiveDocument->Close(false);

        $word->Quit();
        $word = null;
        unset($word);   
?>
```

for More Info Refer  [this](http://www.developertutorials.com/tutorials/php/extracting-text-from-word-documents-via-php-and-com-81/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google Docs:

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://www.example.com/report.doc"></iframe>
```